# Check if input string contains date(specially in the format yy-mm-dd) using python

Tags: python, datetime, if-statement

I am trying to check if the string entered by the user contains date using python.

something like this.

```
user_input = ("Enter date")
if user_input==#type of date(yyyy-mm-dd):
    print(okay)
else:
    print("failed")
```

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dateutil library is your best friend when it comes to parsing dates:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import *
>>> parse('2003-12-23')
datetime.datetime(2003, 12, 23, 0, 0)
>>> parse('2003-12-32')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\srv\venv\dev\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py", line 1356, in parse
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "c:\srv\venv\dev\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py", line 653, in parse
    ret = self._build_naive(res, default)
  File "c:\srv\venv\dev\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py", line 1227, in _build_naive
    naive = default.replace(**repl)
ValueError: day is out of range for month
>>>
```

If you want to be more restrictive, ie. only accept dates with the `YYYY-MM-DD` format, then checking with a regex first might be your thing:

```
def is_date(ds):
    if re.match(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', ds):
         return bool(parse(ds))
    return False

>>> is_date('2003-12-23')
True
>>> is_date('2003-12-32')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in is_date
  File "c:\srv\venv\dev\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py", line 1356, in parse
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "c:\srv\venv\dev\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py", line 653, in parse
    ret = self._build_naive(res, default)
  File "c:\srv\venv\dev\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py", line 1227, in _build_naive
    naive = default.replace(**repl)
ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

If you don't want to be *quite* as restrictive, but accept *all* iso-formatted dates, then:

```
from dateutil.parser import isoparse
>>> isoparse('2003-12-23')
datetime.datetime(2003, 12, 23, 0, 0)
>>> isoparse('20031223')
datetime.datetime(2003, 12, 23, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Generally yes, but it depends on whether you want to accept anything that looks like a valid date, or need to validate a date string in a specific format.

Answer (score -1):

This is what you want:

```py
>>> import datetime
>>> def validate(date_text):
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(date_text, '%Y-%m-%d')
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("Incorrect data format, should be YYYY-MM-DD")


>>> validate('2003-12-23')
>>> validate('2003-12-32')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
    validate('2003-12-32')
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 5, in validate
    raise ValueError("Incorrect data format, should be YYYY-MM-DD")
ValueError: Incorrect data format, should be YYYY-MM-DD
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be a "day out of range" error (the format seems to be YYY-MM-DD...)

Comment: I'd probably not even bother catching and raising a custom `ValueError`... the default `ValueError` message (and arguments) raised is descriptive enough and contains additional information to immediately see what the problem is...

Comment: @thebjorn fix it